# How to extract the soap:address from WSDL file?

Tags: soap, wsdl, wsdl2java

may I check, how can I use Java to retrieve the soap:address element from https://www.dataaccess.com/webservicesserver/NumberConversion.wso?WSDL?

```
<port name="NumberConversionSoap" binding="tns:NumberConversionSoapBinding">
**<soap:address location="https://www.dataaccess.com/webservicesserver/NumberConversion.wso"/>**
</port>
```

I tried to use the javax.wsdl.Definition to check through the variable to see where the soap:address is stored, but couldn't find it.

Can someone please advise?

I am currently using java to convert the SOAP WS into REST OpenAPI format using the https://github.com/wso2/soap-to-rest

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find the answer in this web page: https://vvratha.blogspot.com/2013/11/get-wsdl-service-address-with-wsdl4j.html

Hopefully it is useful for someone else.

[image]

[image]

[image]